# c++ how to make two statement sql work with OLEDB?

Tags: c++, sql-server, oledb

I have the following SQL statement:

```
USE "ws_results_db_2011_09_11_09_06_24";SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables WHERE table_name like 'NET_%_STAT' order by table_name
```

I am using the following C++ code to execute it:

```
IDBCreateCommandPtr spDBCreateCommand = GetTheDBCreateCommandPointer();
ICommandTextPtr spCommandText;
spDBCreateCommand->CreateCommand(NULL, IID_ICommandText, reinterpret_cast<IUnknown **>(&spCommandText));
spCommandText->SetCommandText(DBGUID_SQL, GetTheQueryText());
IRowsetPtr spRowset;
spCommandText->Execute(NULL, IID_IRowset, NULL, NULL, reinterpret_cast<IUnknown **>(&spRowset));
RowHandles hRows(spRowset, 0);
ULONG   rowCount;
ULONG maxRowCount = 1;
spRowset->GetNextRows(DB_NULL_HCHAPTER, 0, maxRowCount, &rowCount, hRows.get_addr());
```

Two notes:

1. Error handling is omitted for brevity
2. `RowHandles` implements the RAII concept for `HROW *`

Anyway, I fail to execute the two SQL statements. What happens is that `spCommandText->Execute` returns `S_OK`, but sets `spRowset` to `NULL`.

If I execute the same `spCommandText->Execute` the second time (by moving back the instruction pointer during the debugging session), then a valid `IRowset` pointer is returned - I successfully obtain the correct column information using it. But `spRowset->GetNextRows` sets `rowCount` to `0` and returns `DB_S_ENDOFROWSET` - no luck.

The code is working fine when I execute a single SQL statement.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is up to the client to split the sql commands - isql does this on the ; ie you are asking for two commands the use and the select.
So the fix is to do the two commands by separate sets of  CreateCommands and execute.

Also note in this case you can do the commands as one SQL statement

```
SELECT table_name FROM ws_results_db_2011_09_11_09_06_24.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables 
  WHERE table_name like 'NET_%_STAT' 
  order by table_name
```